# Navigation drawer in android is not full screen

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, sidebar, navigation-drawer

Since the google has introduced the navigation drawer, I tried to use this component to create a facebook-like menu. The problem is , the visual effect is seems to be different.

**The google one has the action bar retain when the drawer is open while the facebook one does not.Instead, the whole screen has pushed to right side**

I have found there are some lib can achieve this, but since I prefer not include third party lib in the project, are there any way to achieve this ? Thanks

[image: Google:]

[image: Facebook:]

Code based on navigation drawer tutorial

```
protected void setupMenu(List<String> list, final ListView menu) {
        Adapter customAdapter = new Adapter(getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                R.layout.item, list);
        menu.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        menu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    final int pos, long id) {
                String selected = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTxt))
                        .getText().toString();
                // define pass data
                final Bundle bData = new Bundle();
                bData.putString("itemSelect", selected);

                drawer.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                        FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction();
                        tx.replace(R.id.mainContent, Fragment.instantiate(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                "com.example.utilities.ContentPage", bData));
                        tx.commit();
                    }
                });

                drawer.closeDrawer(menu);
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well creating a custom navigation drawer is the best solution for you.
I understand you do not want to use third party but this can be a quick solution to your problem Sliding Menu Lib [link](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/).

Answer (score 3):

Hope this Helps.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >
        <include
            layout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            />
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Remove the last two lines 
in the default code

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick solution that worked for me :

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        **android:layout_width="320dp"**
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        layout="@layout/drawer"/>
```

Set width of included layout . For devices with different screen size you can dynamically set the width of this included layout .

All the best !!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you will check source code of DrawerLayout, you will see, that resposnible for this minimum margin is the variable mMinDrawerMargin

So, there are atleast 2 solutions(tricks)
1. extend DrawerLayout and set this variable to 0 with reflection.
call this method from all constructors.

```
private void init() {
    try {
        Field declaredField = getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mMinDrawerMargin");
        declaredField.setAccessible(true);

        declaredField.setInt(declaredField, 0);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

2. not so tricky

overryde onMeasure method like this

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // taken from parents logic
    float density = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int minMargin = (int) (64.0F * density + 0.5F);

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    int newWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widthSize + minMargin, widthMode);

    super.onMeasure(newWidth, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

I also created sample project here https://bitbucket.org/wnc_21/fsnavigationdrawer

Comment: First method throws me illegal argument exception, second one not working :(

Comment: provide stacktrace please. Did you try to run the project from bitbucket, I provided?

Answer (score 0):

this problem is caused by margin so we have to reset the width :
i solved this problem by implementing DrawerListener and wrapping ListView inside a LinearLayout for making rooms for other views beside list view

here is my listener

```
public class NavigationDrawer implements DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    protected boolean expanded = false;

    NavigationDrawer(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public NavigationDrawer bindDrawerLayout(int id) {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) activity.findViewById(id);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this);
        return this;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        if (!expanded) {
            Log.i("margin", "here we are");
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
            layout.getLayoutParams().width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            layout.requestLayout();
            expanded = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

    }

}
```

here is my layout :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/application_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/application_content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/application_left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement like facebook sliding menu, then you to use androids [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) instead of NavigationDrawer.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#CC00FF00" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="match_parent"
        android:background="#CC0000FF" >
        // add toolbar and other required layouts
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

add toolbar instead of actionbar and apply no actionbar theme.